# Determine whether the following map is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

So I have to determine if the following is a linear transformation: $$T: F(I) \rightarrow F(I)$$ defined by: $$T(f) = 2f$$

I know that if you let $T: V\rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. Then:

a. $T(cu) = cT(u)$ for all $v$ in $V$.
b. $T(u-v) = T(u)-T(v)$ for all $u$ and $v$ in $V$.

So I think I am supposed to let $f_1,f_2$ be in $F$ (or maybe $I$??) and let a scalar $c$ be a real number as well and put them into a, b and solve them for the proof but I'm not sure how I would apply this for this question since the definition of the transformation is $T(f) = 2f$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is $F(I)$?

Comment: Linearity is $T(af + bg) = aT(f) + bT(g)$ where $a,b$ are elements of the underlying field

Answer (score 1):

Your "vectors" are elements of $F(I)$, which are functions on the interval(?) $I$. Note that the zero "vector" is actually a function that sends everything to zero.

Your scalars are probably real numbers. They need to be in a field (e.g. real numbers, complex numbers) and should not be in $F(I)$.

Finally, I think you should use the definition of linearity that Ilya posted in the comment above; in particular I don't think $T(cv)=c T(v)$ is implied by the three conditions that you wrote.

Comment: Yeah the question is in the interval $I$. And okay I understand about the scalar. And hmm yeah I just noticed I wrote down the wrong condition, I'll edit it.